# C++ Fork/Exec Parent Child communication

Tags: java, c++, fork, minecraft

I'm writing a C++ console program on Ubuntu to manage a game server "Minecraft" specifically, writing it for learning purposes so open to any option, it does have to follow what I've done.

I want to execute the minecraft server and then be able to check if it's still alive, I also want to be able to send commands to it from the C++ program like "/stop" which will gracefully shut it down instead of just using "kill".

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
cout << pid << endl;

switch (pid)
{
    case -1:
        break;
    case 0:
        cout << "Child Process" << endl;

        //WAITS HERE, CANT MOVE ON, IS THERE A FIX?
        execlp("java", "java", "-jar", filetoexec, "nogui");
        cerr << "Failed" << endl;
        while(true)
        {
            //WANT if (isMinecraftAlive()) echo yay!!!
            cout << "Child Tick..." << getpid() << endl;
            sleep(4);
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Parent Process" << endl;
        while(true)
        {
            cout << "Parent Tick..." << getpid() << endl;
            //WANT TO SEND "/list" to CHILD and it EXEC on MINECRAFT;
            sleep(4);
        }
        //execv("test", NULL);
        break;
}
```

## What I want to do:

After the "`execlp("java", "java", "-jar", filetoexec, "nogui");`", I want to be able to do an `IsAlive()` on it, basically making sure the server is still responding. I noticed the `execlp` waits for the process to finish what it's doing before moving on which is an issue since it's a game server so alive forever.

All help is greatly appreciated and as I said above this is a learning task but I'm stumped on this.

Comment: What problem are you having, exactly?

Comment: Well you rattled off a good set of features. Is there a specific one you're having a problem with?

Comment: Sorry, should of been more specific.

Comment: After the "execlp("java", "java", "-jar", filetoexec, "nogui");", I want to be able to do an IsAlive() on it, basically making sure the server is still responding. I noticed the execlp waits for the process to finish what it's doing before moving on which is an issue since it's a game server so alive forever.